# $http.get status error 0 when executing php script ionic angularjs

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http, ionic-framework

I am getting a status error 0 when loading this controller in ionic. (angularjs)
The php script is called from a wamp server on given ip adress.
It should

```
.controller('FloorplanCtrl', function($scope, $http, BeaconData, DataBase, DateService) {

  $scope.path = '';
  $scope.url = "192.168.43.5/EE5/SQLReadDatabase.php";

  $http.get($scope.url)
  .success(function(response) {
    $scope.path = response[1][6];
    alert(path);
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("error " + status );
  });

})
```

It works with this ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: IPAdress + "/EE5/SQLReadDatabase.php",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { type:"readDatabase"},
                    ContentType:"application/json",
                    success: function (response)
                    {
                        Array = response;
                        for(var i=0;i<Array.length;i++){
                            Array[i][2] = moment(Array[i][2]);
                            Array[i][3] = moment(Array[i][3]);

                        }
                        localStorage["messages"] = JSON.stringify(Array);
                        document.write("Done reading database");

                    }
```

Comment: In the Angular $http version you don't seem to be sending the same request - you are not sending `type:"readDatabase"`.

Comment: ok I found the problem:
I had to put "http://" in front of the ip.......................

Answer (score 2):

As said as comment of your post you don't seem to be sending the same request `type` is missing in your url

```
.controller('FloorplanCtrl', function($scope, $http, BeaconData, DataBase, DateService) {

      $scope.path = '';
      $scope.url = "http://192.168.43.5/EE5/SQLReadDatabase.php";

      $http.get($scope.url+"?type=readDatabase")
      .success(function(response) {
        $scope.path = response[1][6];
        alert(path);
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("error " + status );
      });

    })
```

Comment: Url 7192.168.43.5/EE5/SQLReadDatabase.php is reachable? copy and paste your url in a browser and tell me what does it give.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS transmits data using

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

some Web server languages—notably PHP—do not unserialize it natively. It means you have to follow certain steps to make it work. 
Add the following code to your config

```
// Your app's root module...
angular.module('MyModule', [], function($httpProvider) {
// Use x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';

/**
* The workhorse; converts an object to x-www-form-urlencoded serialization.
* @param {Object} obj
* @return {String}
*/ 
var param = function(obj) {
var query = '', name, value, fullSubName, subName, subValue, innerObj, i;

for(name in obj) {
  value = obj[name];

  if(value instanceof Array) {
    for(i=0; i<value.length; ++i) {
      subValue = value[i];
      fullSubName = name + '[' + i + ']';
      innerObj = {};
      innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
      query += param(innerObj) + '&';
    }
  }
  else if(value instanceof Object) {
    for(subName in value) {
      subValue = value[subName];
      fullSubName = name + '[' + subName + ']';
      innerObj = {};
      innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
      query += param(innerObj) + '&';
    }
  }
  else if(value !== undefined && value !== null)
    query += encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&';
}

return query.length ? query.substr(0, query.length - 1) : query;
};

// Override $http service's default transformRequest
$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function(data) {
return angular.isObject(data) && String(data) !== '[object File]' ? param(data) : data;
 }];
});
```

Taken from:
http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/

I have applied it to my project and it worked, so good luck :D

Comment: this might be appropriate if the "working" `$.ajax` call didn't have `ContentType:"application/json"` set on it...